# How to delete foreign key as well as primary key

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I want to use SQL and PHP to delete a specific row, events, and the foreign key eventlocation along with it. I tried to use an inner join function, but this gave me an error. Any ideas?

```
DELETE FROM Events, EventLocation JOIN ON EventLocation.EventLocationID = Events.EventLocationID WHERE EventID = '".$_POST["id"]."' AND EventLocationID = '".$_POST["id"]."'
```

Comment: Please be aware that you should **NEVER** use `$_POST` (or equivalent variables) directly in SQL statements! You should use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead, binding your `$_POST` variables to parameters. Given your code above, you have a serious security vulnerability -- a malicious user could easily `DROP` your entire database or possibly even worse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**use inner join**

```
DELETE Events, EventLocation FROM Events INNER JOIN EventLocation WHERE Events.EventID=EventLocation.EventID
```

Answer (score 0):

Well bellow query works fine.

`DELETE Events, EventLocation 
     FROM Events INNER JOIN EventLocation 
 WHERE Events.EventID=EventLocation.EventID`

**But** in this case you handle easily if the table `EventLocation` setting **Cascade On Delete** with `EventID` whwres `EventID` is a foreign key of table `EventLocation` and primary key of table `Events`.
Then you just delete row of `Events`. So the row of `EventLocation` delete autometically which along with `Events`.